# Removing InnoDB indexes causes database table almost not accessible and slow

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.1, index-maintenance

I have a server with 32GB RAM. I have given almost 70% InnoDB buffer pool to it. I have table with almost 40 million rows. Recently, I tried to remove one of the indexes and replace it with another. My whole system could not work any more and it was not able to see my db.

I could see a lot of this error in my application:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
No operations allowed after statement closed.
```

Also I saw a lot of too "many file open" errors on my application due to this process.

I had to stop the database, truncate the table, and start afresh. Is this an InnoDB limitation? In future, what can I do to avoid this? What other limitations do I need to be aware of?

Is it not advisable to remove indexes when the size reaches big as few millions like this?

Is it a good reason for my to swap to TokuDB?

Below is my table description:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mainData` (
  `mainDataID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `deviceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `gpdateTime` datetime NOT NULL,   
  `linkID` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `eventID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dataInsertDateTime` datetime NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`mainDataID`,`dataInsertDateTime`),
  KEY `gpdateTime` (`gpdateTime`),
  KEY `linkID` (`linkID`),
  KEY `eventID` (`eventID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=50425561 ;
```

This was on a running production system with heavy inserts going in so that is why all almost halted. When tables reach a huge sum in million how to best to say remove and replace a new index?

My version is 5.1.73. I know kind of old; as you know CentOS goes for stability. What I did was removing the `gpdateTime` index via PHPMyAdmin and everything started to fall apart. My OS which I am running is Centos 6.8.

Comment: I still don't see the `ALTER`.  "Fall apart" -- Perhaps you have queries that say `WHERE gpdateTime ...`?  (I don't _yet_ see an issue with 5.1, in spite of how old it is.) "almost halted" -- How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mainData'`

Comment: @RickJames sorry I am lost when you say Alter is it table design statement ?  Yes I have a number of queries WHERE gpdateTime. I have 32Gb ram in total and my innodb_buffer_pool=22G .  I ran this query SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mainData' but it gives Empty set (0.00 sec)? I did the removal of the index via phpmyadmin gui so I did not do via sql statement.

Comment: table status -- were you in the appropriate database? Probably phpmyadmin created the SQL `ALTER TABLE mainData DROP INDEX ...` and executed it. It would take some time to alter a 40M row table; how long did you wait? Seems like it would fit in RAM, that is, not be too "I/O-bound".  (`TABLE STATUS` was a check on such.) `a lot of too "many file open"` -- Now I will suggest that other connections were stalled waiting for the `ALTER` to finish.

Comment: @RickJames yes I am sure I am in the right db and table when I did that operation. It was like forever even after 24 hours the same.  So in future I should use table status to do what type of check? So in future I should do it via command line and what is the correct command to remove indexed ?

Comment: Please show us the command(s) for "I tried to remove one of the indexes and replace it with another."

Comment: @RickJames I failed to do that cause I got stucked could not operate the db any more.

Comment: Don't you remember the command(s) you issued?

Comment: @RickJames if you recalled remember I did all via the phpmyadmin gui where I can see the list of index and I just click on delete button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.1 `ALTERs` work faster if you perform them simultaneously:

```
ALTER TABLE mainData
    DROP INDEX foo,
    ADD INDEX (col1, col2);
```

You can perform that in the UI window that lets you perform arbitrary SQL.  It will be twice as fast (in older versions) than doing the `DROP` and `ADD` separately.  This is because each `ALTER` (not each clause in it) involves a complete copy of the data, plus a complete rebuild of the resulting set of indexes.

Comment: thank for the script. In future say I have this table grown to 100 million or more data then if I need to adjust any indexes. Should I first copy the table to another location and test your script or can I do on the live system? I am worried in my live system the data will be keep inserted in so  how will this effect the db ?

Comment: @user5313398 - Focus _now_ on upgrading.  5.1 is _old_.  5.6 has a significant improvement in `ALTER ... INDEX...` -- it happens "inplace", hence _much_ less invasive.  In 5.1, it might take hours (depends mostly on disk speed).

Comment: thank you for your help. I think there is a problem here on the upgrades cause this server is in environment with no external internet access so I dont think we can upgrade for now.  So are you saying if the same operation done on 5.6 its much faster even with the live data being inserted.

Comment: Faster in 5.6; I can't say how much faster.  Start by reading the first paragraph of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#innodb-online-ddl-summary-grid 
 Then move on to  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#innodb-online-ddl-summary-grid